# Why is the OpenGL projection matrix needlessly complicated?

Tags: opengl, matrix, graphics, projection

The following image shows the main values used in calculating the perspective projection matrix in OpenGL. They are labelled "HALFFOV", "RIGHT", "LEFT", "NEAR" AND "NEAR x 2":

[image]

Now, as you'll see in the following picture, to figure out the x value after projection supposedly it does 2 x NEAR divided by RIGHT - LEFT. The fact is that 2 x NEAR divided by RIGHT - LEFT is the same as simply doing NEAR / RIGHT. In both cases you're simply doubling, doubling the NEAR, and doubling the RIGHT, so the fraction is the same.

Also, in the 3rd column there are operations where there should be zeroes, for example: RIGHT + LEFT divided by RIGHT - LEFT always ends up being 0 / RIGHT - LEFT, which is always zero.

[image]

When the GLM math library makes a perspective projection matrix for me those two that always end up zero are always zero.

Why is it that the matrix is written like this? Are there certain cases for which my assumptions are wrong?

Comment: Your assumption only holds for abs(right) == abs(left) (and abs(top) == abs(bottom)). In case of off-center projections this is simply not the case.

Comment: @BDL I see. Well actually when LEFT is defined as -RIGHT and BOTTOM is defined as -TOP, they are equal. I'm not sure if the tutorial I was working off got this wrong. Where are off-centre projections used in graphics or games? Are they used for any effects?

Comment: Off-center projections are very important where the assumption that the user looks into the center of the screen does not hold true. Examples for that are CAVEs, Powerwalls, Virtual Reality headsets, and Anaglyph rendering. Robert Kooima has a nice summary: http://csc.lsu.edu/~kooima/articles/genperspective/

Comment: @skalarproduktraum What would happen if you kept the same centred view frustum but just offset it left and right by the half the distance between each eye, and rotated inwards a bit, which was my naive way of thinking about it, and in the article mentions is the wrong way to do it?

Comment: That would lead to centered frustums, just being shifted left or right. While it may look convincing first, you'll soon notice that it doesn't lead to convergence of the two frustums in the image plane (like you get with off-center, see http://csc.lsu.edu/~kooima/articles/genperspective/teapot-scene.svg). And this convergence is needed to have objects "pop out" of the screen, or being seen as behind the screen.

Answer (score 6):

> Why is it that the matrix is written like this?

Because a symmetrical, view centered projection is just one of many possibilities. Sometimes you want to skew and/or shift the planes for certain effects or rendering techniques.

> Are there certain cases for which my assumptions are wrong?

For example plane parallel shifting the view frustum is required for tiled rendering (not to be confused with a tiled rasterizer) where the image to be rendered is split up into a grid of tiles, each one rendered individually and then merged later. This is needed if the desired output images resolution exceeds the maximum viewport/renderbuffer size limits of the used OpenGL implementation.

Other cases are if you want to simulate tilt-shift photography.

And last but not least a shifted projection matrix is required for stereoscopic rendering targeting a fixed position screen display device, that's viewed using 3D glasses.

(Rendering for headmounted displays requires a slightly different projection setup).